# Insert style and chart into a csv file (exported from <script>)

Tags: javascript, php, html, linux, export-to-csv

I got a problem on my code.
I want to export an HTML table to a CSV file (Libre Office Calc, idc if it's csv, xls or xlsx, I just want it to run on Linux Server).
I found this code online and it's working really fine (only the script, and I edited it a bit) :

```
<span onclick="exportData('total-concours-table', 'Total_Concours_<?php echo date('dmy-Hi'); ?>')" id="print-total-concours" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; font-size: 50px"><i class="fa-solid fa-print"></i></span>

<table id="total-concours-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Type de Dossier</th>
                <th>Nombre Total (<?= $totalConcours ?>)</th>
                <th>Pourcentage</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>En cours</td>
                <td><?= $totalConcoursEncours ?></td>
                <td><?= $prcCEncours ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cloturé</td>
                <td><?= $totalConcoursCloture ?></td>
                <td><?= $prcCCloture ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>En cours</td>
                <td><?= $totalConcoursAnnule ?></td>
                <td><?= $prcCAnnule ?></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

<script>
            function exportData(tablename, nomfichier){
                /* Get the HTML data using Element by Id */
                let table = document.getElementById(tablename);

                /* Declaring array variable */
                let rows = [];

                //iterate through rows of table
                for(var i=0; row = table.rows[i]; i++){
                    //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
                    //Get each cell value/column from the row
                    column1 = row.cells[0].innerText;
                    column2 = row.cells[1].innerText;
                    column3 = row.cells[2].innerText;

                    /* add a new records in the array */
                    rows.push(
                        [
                            column1,
                            column2,
                            column3
                        ]
                    );

                }
                csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
                /* add the column delimiter as comma(,) and each row splitted by new line character (\n) */
                rows.forEach(function(rowArray){
                    row = rowArray.join(",");
                    csvContent += row + "\r\n";
                });

                /* create a hidden <a> DOM node and set its download attribute */
                var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
                nomfinal = nomfichier + '.csv';
                link.setAttribute("download", nomfinal);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                /* download the data file named "Stock_Price_Report.csv" */
                link.click();
            }
        </script>
```

BUT, when I download it, I can't have any css or design for the cells. I don't want blur effect, I only want a background for the th (on the csv file).

Can You help me?

The second point is that I want to make a chart (pie or/and bar) next to the csv array, do you know how I can do this?

Thank in advance :)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to apply a color to some cells of a CSV? Because that's not how CSVs work. They're comma-separated values and that's it.

Comment: Mmh, so I don't want CSV haha
I want to export table in an Excel (Libre Office Calc) file.

Comment: To be able to format the data, then you need to create a proper Excel document, using something like [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) or similar in PHP, not JS.

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for Comma-separated values, i.e. data separated by commas. This format can contain nothing but data and a delimiter.

If you need beauty - you need xml or xlsx. And it's complicated.